# Beamer - Make "alert" font highlighted

Tags: beamer, highlighting, slideshow

In the Beamer class, How can I make the `\alert` font highlighted as in `\hl`?
Then, how can I make it so a word is alerted (highlighted) for only one slide?
i.e., I want this to be the output: 
Slide 1: `${x^{\alert{2}} - x - 1}$`
Slide 2: `${x^{2} - x - \alert{1}}$`
Slide 3: `${x^{2} - x - 1}$`

This is the code I added in order to get `\hl` to work in Beamer:

```latex
\makeatletter
\let\HL\hl
\renewcommand\hl{
  \let\set@color\beamerorig@set@color
  \let\reset@color\beamerorig@reset@color
  \HL}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to TEX S.E. Please provide a fully compiliable MWE, i.e. a piece of code that can directly be compiled, without adding anything to it by hand.